# looping over inside a context in rspec doesn't set the let variable correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, rspec-rails

```
MY_HASH = {
  user_id: [:email, :first_name],
  email: [:last_name]
}

context "when object's single attribute changed" do
  let(:object) { double("my_object", :changed? => true) }

  before do
    allow(object).to receive("#{attribute}_changed?").and_return(true)
  end

  after do
    allow(object).to receive("#{attribute}_changed?").and_return(false)
  end

  MY_HASH.each do |attr, dependent_attrs|
    let(:attribute) { attr }

    it "should have all dependent attributes in right order for defaulting attribute" do
      expect(subject.send(:my_method)).to eq(dependent_attrs)
    end
  end
end
```

here attribute is always evaluated to `email`. I want to iterate over each attribute one by one.

Can anyone help me understand what's going wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: Firstly, please take note of the advice we always give around posting StackOverflow questions with a [mcve]. Your question is not minimal (what relevance do all of these `before/after/double` lines have?), it's not complete (what is `subject`? This snippet of code isn't executable.), and it's not verifiable (what do you mean by "attribute is always `email`"? What command are you running/debugging are you performing/output are you seeing that made you make that statement? How can we reproduce the same behaviour you describe?

Comment: My **guess** (!!!) is that you're only running a specific iteration of the loop from the command line - something like: `rspec spec/your_filename_spec.rb[1:2]`. If you run the whole file, or run against a line number rather than a nested context number, then you'll find both values are evaluated. I don't see anything wrong with your code. But as I said above, I can't be certain of this since the explanation you gave is currently incomplete and non-verifiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're redefining `attribute` each loop:

```
  MY_HASH.each do |attr, dependent_attrs|
    let(:attribute) { attr }
```

To fix this, you could introduce a new context/describe block for each iteration:

```
  MY_HASH.each do |attr, dependent_attrs|
    describe("#{attr}") do
      let(:attribute) { attr }
      it "should have all dependent attributes ..." do
        # content of test here
      end
    end
  end
```